# Jquery area mouseover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm on a worpress website and i try to make a mandala with changing images.

I use jquery, and area from css, when the mouse is over a section delimited by an area, i display the image corresponding.
But there is an issue, when i put the mouse over, it take some time(1s) before displaying the image, and when i put the mouse over another section, it's not working well eather..

I think the issue is due to the fact that the new displayed image comes over the mouseover section delimited by the area

here is the html code:

```
<div class="mandala">
    <img id="mandala_img" src="http://example.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/background.png" usemap="#mandala_map">
    <div id="image1"></div>
    <div id="image2"></div>
    <div id="image3"></div>
    <div id="image4"></div>
    <div id="image5"></div>
    <div id="image6"></div>
    <div id="image7"></div>
    <div id="image8"></div>
    <map name="mandala_map" id="mandala_map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="310,10,422,33,498,87,430,154,383,121,310,106" href="http://example.org/site/" id="area_image1">
    <area shape="poly" coords="498,87,430,154,479,274,576,274,557,178" href="http://example.org/site/" id="area_image2">
    <area shape="poly" coords="479,275,576,275,553,383,499,462,430,393,463,348" href="http://example.org/site/" id="area_image3">
    <area shape="poly" coords="499,462,430,393,310,442,310,540,420,516" href="http://example.org/site/" id="area_image4">
    <area shape="poly" coords="310,442,310,540,206,518,124,462,192,393" href="http://example.org/site/" id="area_image5">
<!--    <area shape="poly" coords="124,462,192,393," href="http://example.org/site/" id="area_image2">
    <area shape="poly" coords="" href="http://example.org/site/" id="area_image2">
    <area shape="poly" coords="" href="http://example.org/site/" id="area_image2">-->
    </map>
</div>
```

js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.mandala area').each(function () {
    // Assigning an action to the mouseover event
    $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
        var image = $(this).attr('id').replace('area_', '');
        $('#image1').css('display', 'none');
        $('#image2').css('display', 'none');
        $('#image3').css('display', 'none');
        $('#image4').css('display', 'none');
        $('#image5').css('display', 'none');
        $('#image6').css('display', 'none');
        $('#image7').css('display', 'none');
        $('#image8').css('display', 'none');
        $('#' + image).css('display', 'block');
    });
});
</script>
```

the mandala looks like this:

[image: Mandala with 8 sections]

The image displayed on the mouse over looks like this:

[image]

thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe the each event is not the best solution. Have you try to pass an event for each area. <aera id="laviedanslanature" ..> and then $("#laviedanslanature").onmouseover=function(){monImage1.css('display', 'block')}

Comment: here is a suggestion... why dont you map the areas on a transparent screen in front of the image and based on hover over partcular area, change the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my suggestion, I have made a basic rough fiddle. It is not quite smooth yet but this is just to give proof of concept to my suggestion.

All I am doing is change the background image based on which area is hovered by using a transparent screen for image map

[Fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tL8h007/)

Snippet as follows..

```js
    $("#area_image1").mouseover(function(e) {
      $('.mandala').css("background", "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xypLJ.png') no-repeat center");
    });
    $("#area_image1").mouseout(function(e) {
      $('.mandala').css("background", "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/A690W.png')");
    });
```

```css
.mandala {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/A690W.png");
  display: inline-block;
}
#mandala_img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mandala">
  <img id="mandala_img" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x541.png&text=sample" width="600" height="541" usemap="#mandala_map">
  <map name="mandala_map" id="mandala_map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="310,10,422,33,498,87,430,154,383,121,310,106" href="#area_image1" id="area_image1" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="498,87,430,154,479,274,576,274,557,178" href="#area_image2" id="area_image2" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="479,275,576,275,553,383,499,462,430,393,463,348" href="#area_image3" id="area_image3">
    <area shape="poly" coords="499,462,430,393,310,442,310,540,420,516" href="#area_image4" id="area_image4" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="310,442,310,540,206,518,124,462,192,393" href="#area_image5" id="area_image5" />
  </map>
</div>
```

**Again this is just a proof of concept**. Please do not tell me that this does not work the way you want exactly

Hope this helps.